# Animated gif alternative with broad browser support?

Tags: animation, gif, animated, webp, apng

I would like to insert an animated image to a blog and a forum (hence I can't use javascript, CSS, SVG, HTML5 and other tricks), but the gif animation is too big, about 700K. It was made of a photo, so I can't reduce the colours below 256 palette entries, and the size of the image is also fixed to 350 pixel in height.
I tried to convert it to "webp" animation with utility called "gif2webp", size reduced very much to 200K only. However it doesn't display in my favourite Opera browser. Than I tried "apng" format with utility "gif2apng", size was reduced again to 400K, but unfortunately the animation doesn't show up in Google Chrome Stable version. Is there any other alternative for a simple animation which can be inserted to a webpage as a simple image with the "img src=" HTML tag and which is supported by all major browsers?

Comment: As much as I cringe to say this, the only other possibility I can think of would be Flash.

Answer (score 3):

**Update, 7 July 2020**

WebP is the best alternative to GIF and is nearly supported by all browsers. It's been supported by Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge for a few years already. Coming soon, it will be supported by Safari 14 and iOS Safari. WebP file size is much smaller than GIF - often 60-85% smaller. WebP also supports transparency and isn't constrained to 256 colours like GIF is.

APNG is supported by Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Edge, so that makes it an alternative to GIF. APNG supports 24 bit colour and transparency, so you can have much higher quality images than GIF but file sizes are huge - even bigger than GIF.

Instead, you can stick with GIF, which is supported by all browsers. To reduce file size, apply lossy compression. By applying 80% lossy compression to this GIF below, it reduced the file size from 424.7 kB to 253.1 kb, which is a 40% reduction.

[image]

GIF without lossy compression: https://sirv.sirv.com/Examples/drill/drill.spin?image&scale.height=300

GIF with 80% lossy compression: https://sirv.sirv.com/Examples/drill/drill.spin?image&scale.height=300&gif.lossy=80

Depending on the complexity and size of your source image, you could even achieve a file size reduction up to 60%, though it may be as little as 25%. A lot depends on your particular image.